# Multivariate interpolation error in GML

Tags: linear-interpolation

everybody.  I am using Game Maker, a program with syntax somewhat similar to Python (aside from spacing) to implement interpolation between multiple data values, as described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/475931/1-d-interpolation-between-any-number-of-points).  Imagine a scatterplot with x = 0 at the origin and x = 100 at the end, with equal spacing between each data value.  The x-positions are constant, but the y-positions may have any value.  If lines were connected between each data point, then ideally, a script would be able to find the y for a given x-position.  Here was my original implementation:

```
// This is executed once.

nums = 3; // the number of values to interpolate between
t = 0; // the position along the "scatterplot" of values

// Values may be decimals with any sign.  There should be values >= nums.
ind[0] = 100;
ind[1] = 0;
ind[2] = 100;

//This is executed each step.

intervals = 100 / (nums - 1);
index = round(percent / intervals);
if percent != 0 {newpercent=  (intervals / (percent - index)) / 100;}
else {newpercent = 0;}
newval = ind[index] * (1 - newpercent) + ind[index + 1] * newpercent;
```

This should've used a lerp() after finding which two points surround the given x-position to return an interpolation between their two values, but it didn't, so my question is:
**What went wrong and how could I fix it?**  Thanks in advance.

Edit: Here is the finished and working code:

```
// This is executed once.

nums = 3; // the number of values to interpolate between
t = 0; // the position along the "scatterplot" of values

// Values may be decimals with any sign.  There should be values >= nums.
ind[0] = 100;
ind[1] = 0;
ind[2] = 100;

// This is executed each step; setting the result to 'alpha'.

if (nums > 1) {
    if (t != 1) {
        _temp1 = 1 / (nums - 1);
        _temp2 = floor(t / _temp1);
        _temp3 = (t - (_temp1 * _temp2)) * (nums - 1);
        alpha = ind[_temp2] + _temp3 * (ind[_temp2 + 1] - ind[_temp2]);
    }
    else {
        alpha = ind[nums - 1];
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know Game Maker, but I wouldn't be surprized if it already has some functionality for linear interpolation (often called lerp).

Comment: I knew the function was called lerp() and I checked wikipedia and adapted a version of it to Game Maker, since it is limited.  Game Maker's default language is close in syntax to Python, so you can use that as a reference.  In fact, you can write the code in Python because I can transfer it anyway (if that's more comfortable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is interpolate the value of property of your game (sound volume, danger level, gravity etc.) let's call the variable you want to caluculate `y` as some other property changes (like time, x-position etc.) let's call it `t`.

We have `n` points where we know the value of `y`. Let's call each of these points `p0`, `p1` ... `pn-1` where each number is the `index` of that point. Lets call the values in these points `y0`, `y1` ... `yn-1`.
So for any given value of `t` we want to do the following:

First we find the two points closest to `t`. Since all points are evenly spaced out we know that the value of `t` for a given point is `t = index/(n-1)` and by reordering this equation we can get the "index" of any given t like this `index = t*(n-1)`. When `t` isn't exactly in the same position as one of our points it's going to be a number in between the index values of the two closest points `pk` and `pk1`. So `pk = floor(index)` gets you the index previous to your `t` and `pk1 = pk + 1` is the next point.

Then we have to find out how close `t` is to each of these two points (value between 0 and 1) as that determines how much influence the value from each point will get in out interpolation. Let's call this measurement `alpha`. Then `alpha = (t - pk)/(pk1 - pk)`.

Finally if `pk` and `pk1` have values `yk` and `yk1` you get your interpolated value `y` like this

```
y = (1-alpha)*yk + alpha*yk1;
```

Comment: That formula is still incorrect.  It is also the same as my calculation, with only a slight difference in the fact that it is less efficient (with more variables defined and the formulas sectioned so as to reduce the processing speed of my equivalent formula).  The output is still flawed; it would be nice if you tested the code first.

Comment: The two formulas are not the same. The first difference is that floor is different from round (I don't know gml but I'd be surprized if it's not the case there too). The second difference is in how we calculate alpha/newpercent. As to your comment regarding efficiency; this is not meant to be code but rather explaining linear interpolation adapted to your particular case. Should you put this into code you could do it in the same amount of steps and it would probably be more efficient as there are fewer divisions (divisions are slow).

Comment: It does not work to use round() or floor() because it rounds to the nearest integer (it was code leftover when I used a percent from 0 to 100).  Now we need to round to the nearest hundredths place: `round(number * 100) / 100`